# iOS 2D Transforms: Library to use

Tags: ios, matrix, 2d, transform, cgaffinetransform

I have to perform some 2D transforms under iOS. I know that you can use the transform property of UIView to apply transforms so I am assuming that somewhere there is some optimized code that one could call on. However I'm also pretty sure that this stuff is on top of openGL so...

What could I use to do some simple transforms (fastly) on iOS? I just need to translate and rotate points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CGAffineTransform` one can build combined transformation matrices and then apply them to a `CGPoint`, `CGSize` or `CGRect`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) especially *Applying Affine Transformations*